# Javascript : How do you replace all the characters in the string with space?

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have 2 questions:

1. Suppose if i have a string `"Have a nice day"`
   this is the output I want:  `"               "` (15 spaces)
2. Also how do you create a string dynamically in javascript 
   For eg: in `ruby`

   `"A"*10`
   `"AAAAAAAAAA"`

If the latter is possible I could have done the first one ( something like this. ) `" "*(input.length)`

Comment: why not use regular expressions with the javascript replace function ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Ans for Q1:***

```
var str = "Have a nice day";
str = str.replace(/./g, ' ');
```

***Ans for Q2:***

```
String.prototype.repeat = function(n) {
  return new Array(n+ 1).join(this);
};

"A".repeat(10);
```

Comment: @KrishnaprasadVarma Compared to what?

Comment: new Array(inputKwd.length).join(" ");

VS

inputKwd.replace(/./g, ' ');

Comment: @KrishnaprasadVarma You could measure it yourself :)

Answer (score 4):

It can be achieved using:

```
// returns a string with 10 "A" (one less than the array length, which is 11) 
new Array(11).join("A");
```

Comment: +1 - and 1) of course could be implemented with `new Array("Have a nice day".length).join(" ");`

Comment: off-by-one :) should be `Array(11)`

Comment: Thank you. That was something new to me.

Answer (score 1):

1)
`'Have a nice day'.replace(/./g,' ');`

Answer (score 0):

1.)

```
"Have a nice day".replace(/(.)/g, ' ');
```

2.)

```
(new Array(11)).join('A');
```

Comment: Isn't the grouping in the regex a bit unnecessary?

Answer (score 0):

1. `"Have a nice day".replace(/./g, ' ');`
2. `var str = "Have a nice day";
   (new Array(str.length+1)).join(' ');`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all with one simple way:

```
var myString = "Have a nice day";

var emptyString = cleaner(' ', emptyString.lenght);
var aString = cleaner('A', emptyString.lenght);

var cleaner = function(charColor,length){
    return new Array(length)).join(charColor);
}
```